# EXTRACT QUARTER FROM DATE IN BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i AM TRYING TO CREATE AN ADITIONAL COLUMN WITH A QUARTER VALUE FROM A DATE(case_opening_date FORMATTED AS 2022-09-26 which is a string and needs to be converted into a date), THE FORMAT for the new column SHOULD BE 1(2022) indicating the quarter from that date and in parenthesis the year from that quarter, TRIED THE CODE BELLOW BUT I RECEIVE AN ERROR:
SQL_ANALYSIS_ERROR: No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART FROM STRING. Supported signatures: EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATE); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIMESTAMP [AT TIME ZONE STRING]); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATETIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIME)

```
WITH
  _0 AS (
    SELECT
      *,

      EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM case_opening_date) as Quarter
    FROM MY_TABLE AS _t
  )
SELECT * FROM _0
```

How can i convert case_opening_date into a date and get a new column with the quarter?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Maybe if you fixed your caps lock key?  Or perhaps it's because case_opening_date is a string? `No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART` **FROM STRING**

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot to mention that part, it is in fact a string, how can i get the result? also tried parse_date but it still does not work

Comment: So your actual question is how to convert your string to a date?  If you can't just cast it, ask a new question with sample data, I'm sure someone can help you out.

Comment: STOP SHOUTING. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to shout at people you're asking to help you solve **your** problem. If you don't take the time to make your question readable and understandable, it's difficult to help you. Also see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below

```
select case_opening_date,
  format_date('%Q(%Y)', date(case_opening_date)) as Quarter
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CASE
WHEN extract(month from date) = 1 OR extract(month from date) = 2 OR extract(month from date) = 3 THEN CONCAT('Q4./',LEFT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE)-1 AS STRING),4))
WHEN extract(month from date) = 4 OR extract(month from date) = 5 OR extract(month from date) = 6 THEN CONCAT('Q1./',LEFT(CAST(DATE AS STRING),4))
WHEN extract(month from date) = 7 OR extract(month from date) = 8 OR extract(month from date) = 9 THEN CONCAT('Q2./',LEFT(CAST(DATE AS STRING),4))
WHEN extract(month from date) = 10 OR extract(month from date) = 11 OR extract(month from date) = 12 THEN CONCAT('Q3./',LEFT(CAST(DATE AS STRING),4))
END AS Quarter

OUTPUT: Q4./2022

Considering please the following date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Good Lucky!
(^:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A string of date '2022-09-26' can be treated as a date using `DATE()`:

```
SELECT DATE('2022-09-26');
```

This should return a date value instead of a string.

Another way to do this if your dates are not in YYYY-MM-DD format is to use `PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d','<some date value>')` e.g. `PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d','20220926')` returns a date value of 2022-09-26.

Let's check that DATE() works using your table and field:
`SELECT DATE(case_opening_date) FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 5;`

Now let's extract the quarter + "(" + year + ")":

```
SELECT *,
  CONCAT(
    EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM DATE(case_opening_date)), --convert the date and extract the quarter
    '(',
    EXTRACT(YEAR from DATE(case_opening_date)), -- convert the date and extract the year
    ')'
  ) AS quarteryear
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

An older way of getting the quarter is using `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM field)` and banding them into quarters:

```
SELECT *,
  CONCAT(
    --calculate quarter using month and banding them into 3 month blocks
    CASE
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(case_opening_date)) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN 1
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(case_opening_date)) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN 2
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(case_opening_date)) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN 3
      WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(case_opening_date)) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 4
    END,
    '(',
    EXTRACT(YEAR from DATE(case_opening_date)), -- convert the date and extract the year
    ')'
  ) AS quarteryear
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Some flavours of SQL (e.g. BigQuery) have another way to concatenate, using `||`.

```
SELECT *,
  EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM DATE(case_opening_date))||
  '('||
  EXTRACT(YEAR from DATE(case_opening_date))||
  ')' AS quarteryear
FROM MY_TABLE;
```